# why component library uses optional props, not required

Tags: vue.js, components

My company using ant-desing-vue and ag-grid and i'm develop our components by using them.
And I found out that antd and ag-grid don't have required props.
ALL props are optional and I want to know why but I can't find the answer.
Is there a reason that component library using optional props?

Thank you for reading my question.

I couldn't find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using optional props in a component library provides flexibility and adaptability for developers, allowing you to customize the behavior of the components based on your specific needs without imposing strict requirements.

Many component libraries, like ant-desing-vue or ag-grid, often come with default styles and configurations that aim to provide a pleasant and consistent out-of-the-box experience for users. By making props optional, these libraries allow developers to leverage the default styles and behaviors while still providing the option to customize as needed.